# How to create a model easily convertible to TensorFlow Lite?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

### How to create a TensorFlow model which can be converted to TensorFlow Lite (tflite) and can be used in Android application?

Following the examples in Google ML Crash Course I've created a classifier and trained a model. I've exported the model as **saved model**. I wanted to convert the model to **.tflite** file and use it to **infer on Android**.

Soon (actually later) I understand that my model uses [unsupported operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility) - **ParseExampleV2**.

Here is the classifier I'm using for training the model:

```py
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=[tf.feature_column.numeric_column('pixels', shape=WIDTH * HEIGHT)],
        n_classes=NUMBER_OF_CLASSES,
        hidden_units=[40, 40],
        optimizer=my_optimizer,
        config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(keep_checkpoint_max=1),
        model_dir=MODEL_DIR)
```

**Is there a way to train a model which doesn't use this `tf.ParseExampleV2` operator?**

[image: TensorFlow Lite Model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use [Keras Sequential API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential) instead of [Estimator API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimator).**

If your model is more complex try [Keras functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional).

The Estimator is a high-level API which adds additional complexity to the model.

Here is a sequential model:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, input_dim=WIDTH*HEIGHT, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=rate)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And its schema. Compare it with the one in the question:

[image]

For full example how to convert the model to **tflite** see my project for [classifying slashed-zeros and eights](https://github.com/trayanmomkov/zec).