# Tensorflow Lite Application

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

How to apply custom model to tensorflowlite?
In the instruction i was suppose to paste the model in the assets and remove the download model gradle but when it was applied the application simple crush down, what is the problem?

Edited:

I follow the instruction when using a custom train in tensorflow lite but after changing the api model file to my model and commenting the download model gradle the app simple crash. I tried using custom ai of microsoft general compact and compact[s1] and follow the instruction https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-train-your-own-custom-model-with-tensorflow-object-detection-api-and-deploy-it-into-android-aeacab7fa76f
both din't work, the compact[s1] make the app mess and crash while compact totally crash so, what's the problem, is custom ai simple not usable in tensorflowlite?

this thing show up in debug mode:

````
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to apply delegate: Regular TensorFlow ops are not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link the Flex delegate before inference.
    Node number 328 (FlexNonMaxSuppressionV4) failed to prepare.

        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.applyDelegate(Native Method)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.applyDelegates(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:324)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.init(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:82)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.<init>(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:63)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.java:237)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.create(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:140)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(DetectorActivity.java:112)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.CameraActivity.onPreviewFrame(CameraActivity.java:200)
        at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1222)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)```

Edited v2:
Yes, it show up in netron.
[![this is the image of the other persons model][1]][1]
[![this one is my model in microsoft compact[s1][2]][2]
the other model of microsoft compact is to big for png so, it was saved as svg don't know how to show it here.

[![here is the properties of compact[s1][3]][3]
[![here is the properties of compact][4]][4]
[![here is the properties of other person][5]][5]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtkZ1.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffnOU.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx7dx.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyXrt.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1odl.png
````

Comment: Can you post more informations? Stacktrace, crashreport in logcat? Simplified code?

Comment: i just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

The operators your model uses are not supported by TensorFlow Lite. Here is the list of [supported ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility).

You can see how to create a [model easily convertible to TensorFlow Lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60622834/how-to-create-a-model-easily-convertible-to-tensorflow-lite).

Comment: i don't think the operators are not supported since it was working when I was not using my own model.

Comment: Could you visualize the two models (your and the other) with this tool and attach the diagrams?
https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/